# ggplot Its possible to compare 2 .csv with the same values to know if the value change?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a R script for compare the covid19 cases in the towns of my province. The .csv its upgrade each every 3/5 days, so I want to compare the last upgrade and the previous in order to know if these towns has been add new covid cases, and how much has been add or lost. So I would like to plot the number of new cases. Example : New York 25 cases. +7 New cases

Right now only plot the number of cases in each town.

These are the two last upgrades:

[day 17 of Ago](https://dadesobertes.gva.es/datastore/dump/29899134-80c1-41bf-86cc-340577ab1021?bom=True)

[Day 20 of Ago](https://dadesobertes.gva.es/datastore/dump/dbc2b22c-96a2-4eb2-b4c7-4230c87f26af?bom=True)

This is my code, but only plot the data of a single .csv

```
       library(tidyverse)
    
    library('data.table') 
    
    
    
    dfcsv1 <- read.csv("https://dadesobertes.gva.es/datastore/dump/dbc2b22c-96a2-4eb2-b4c7-4230c87f26af?bom=True", encoding = "UTF-8", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
    colnames(dfcsv1) <- c("code", "code2", "Municipio", "PCR", "TasaPCR", "PCR14", "TasaPCR14", "Muertos", "TasaMuertos")
    
    dfcsv1$TasaMuertos = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfcsv1$TasaMuertos))
    dfcsv1$TasaPCR = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfcsv1$TasaPCR))
    dfcsv1$TasaPCR14 = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfcsv1$TasaPCR14))









dfcsv1 %>%
  filter(PCR14 > 0) %>%
  mutate(Municipio = fct_reorder(Municipio, PCR14)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Municipio, y = PCR14, fill = TasaPCR14)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.6) + 
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(y = PCR14,label = PCR14), hjust= -0.5) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "steelblue", high = "red")
```

this is my chart right now:
[image]

I want some like this. (the green data)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest next approach. As you want to compare values between two datasets you can process them, therefore you can merge and compute the difference of values. Last quantity can be saved in a new variable in order to build a new label. Here the code. I only filtered to some cases in the final plot but you can change that according to what you want:

The data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Data
dfcsv1 <- read.csv('29899134-80c1-41bf-86cc-340577ab1021.csv',stringsAsFactors = F,encoding = 'UTF-8')
dfcsv2 <- read.csv('dbc2b22c-96a2-4eb2-b4c7-4230c87f26af.csv',stringsAsFactors = F,encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

Now we process files:

```
#Process data 1
colnames(dfcsv1) <- c("code", "code2", "Municipio", "PCR", "TasaPCR", "PCR14", "TasaPCR14", "Muertos", "TasaMuertos")
#Format
dfcsv1$TasaMuertos = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfcsv1$TasaMuertos))
dfcsv1$TasaPCR = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfcsv1$TasaPCR))
dfcsv1$TasaPCR14 = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfcsv1$TasaPCR14))
#Process data 2
colnames(dfcsv2) <- c("code", "code2", "Municipio", "PCR", "TasaPCR", "PCR14", "TasaPCR14", "Muertos", "TasaMuertos")
#Format
dfcsv2$TasaMuertos = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfcsv2$TasaMuertos))
dfcsv2$TasaPCR = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfcsv2$TasaPCR))
dfcsv2$TasaPCR14 = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfcsv2$TasaPCR14))
```

In this stage, we merge the data, compute the difference and build the new label:

```
#Merge
dfcsv <- merge(dfcsv1,dfcsv2[,c('Municipio','PCR14')],by='Municipio',all.x = T)
#Compute difference and create the label
dfcsv %>% mutate(Label2 = PCR14.y-PCR14.x) %>% select(-PCR14.y) %>%
  rename(PCR14=PCR14.x) %>%
  #Create final label
  mutate(Label2=ifelse(Label2>0,paste0('+',Label2),
                       ifelse(Label2<0,Label2,
                              ifelse(Label2==0,0,NA))),
         Label2=paste0(PCR14,' (',Label2,')')) -> dfcsv
```

With the new dataframe, we design the plot (I have re used your plot code):

```
#Plot
dfcsv %>%
  filter(PCR14 > 20) %>%
  mutate(Municipio = fct_reorder(Municipio, PCR14)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Municipio, y = PCR14, fill = TasaPCR14)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.6) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(NA,1350))+
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(y = PCR14,label = Label2), hjust= -0.1,size=4) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "steelblue", high = "red")
```

The output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use == operator. It will create a matrix of logical values, that will tell you which values are different. So you store the past data in some object, and compare him with the most recent values. Is important to say that the == operator is very sensitive, so this operator can return a FALSE even if the numbers are essentially the same, especially in numeric columns. So another useful function is near() (I think is from the dplyr package), that will compare each number in two different vector's. Now, if you want to create an automate test to verify if some value in the past data are different, you can encapsulate the previous function's in the all() function, that will test if all the logical values returned are TRUE's.

```
dfcsv1 <- read.csv("https://dadesobertes.gva.es/datastore/dump/dbc2b22c-96a2-4eb2-b4c7-4230c87f26af?bom=True", encoding = "UTF-8", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
colnames(dfcsv1) <- c("code", "code2", "Municipio", "PCR", "TasaPCR", "PCR14", "TasaPCR14", "Muertos", "TasaMuertos")

dfcsv1$TasaMuertos = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfcsv1$TasaMuertos))
dfcsv1$TasaPCR = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfcsv1$TasaPCR))
dfcsv1$TasaPCR14 = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfcsv1$TasaPCR14))


test <- dfcsv1

test == dfcsv1

near(test$TasaPCR, dfcsv1$TasaPCR)

all(test == dfcsv1)
```

Comment: But, where you put the  previous .csv to compare with the new .csv ? i have tried to run your script, but don´t plot me anything. The code give me a lot of [TRUE] lines in the console

Comment: The idea Raul, is to use this matrix with a lot of TRUE's to find if some value has changed. When you find where in you table are those values, you use the subsetting funcion ( [ ), to extract the difference. A better solution to you, would be to just extract the difference of all values, and filter in your plot those differences different than zero.